# Getting "ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation" error while fetching array of varchar from anonymous pl/sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am getting "ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation " exception while fetching the varray of type from anonymous PL/SQL block.

my code is:

```
    Connection con = null;
    CallableStatement cstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String dequeueQuery = "DECLARE " +
            " type namesarray IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10); " +
            " names namesarray;" +
            "   total integer;" +
            "   BEGIN " +

            "   names := namesarray('Kavita', 'Pritam', 'Ayan', 'Rishav', 'Aziz'); " +

            "   ? := names;"+

            " END;";

    try{

            con = getConnection();

            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            cstmt =(OracleCallableStatement )con.prepareCall(dequeueQuery);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
            boolean b = cstmt.execute();
            Array arr = cstmt.getArray(1);

              String[] recievedArray = (String[]) arr.getArray();
              for (int i = 0; i < recievedArray.length; i++)

                System.out.println(recievedArray[i]);

            con.commit();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            con.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }`
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or
> representation

This is caused by the following statement:

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
```

This statement says array will be the output, but didn't specify the actual Oracle Type name as third parameter. You can check this [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/datacc.htm#sthref519) for more information on this.

We can fix the exception "`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation`" by adding a third parameter with actual Oracle Type name. In your case it is `NAMESARRAY`.

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"NAMESARRAY");
```

But the above statement will throw following exception while running:

> java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: SCOTT.NAMESARRAY

This is because we haven't declared the type `NAMESARRAY` inside DB. The above exception says the user as SCOTT, but you can connect to the user of your choice and create type.

**Creating type in DB:**

```
connect scott/tiger
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE namesarray AS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10) ;
/
```

Once we create the type `NAMESARRAY`, if we execute your code without changing we will hit the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 180:
>
> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, column 173:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

This error is because we have already defined the type at user level, but we are trying to create the type again inside the following code block:

```
String dequeueQuery = "DECLARE " +
            " type namesarray IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(10); " +
            " names namesarray;" +
            "   total integer;" +
            "   BEGIN " +
            "   names := namesarray('Kavita', 'Pritam', 'Ayan', 'Rishav', 'Aziz'); " +
            "   ? := names;"+
            " END;";
```

So, we need to remove the type declaration from that.

```
String dequeueQuery = "DECLARE " +
            " names namesarray;" +
            "   total integer;" +
            "   BEGIN " +
            "   names := namesarray('Kavita', 'Pritam', 'Ayan', 'Rishav', 'Aziz'); " +
            "   ? := names;"+
            " END;";
```

After removing it if we execute the program after compilation, we should be able to see the following output:

```
Kavita
Pritam
Ayan
Rishav
Aziz
```

Following is the updated program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;

public class DBQC {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
      Connection con=null;
      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
      String connStr = "jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//dbhost:1521/dbsrvc";
      con=DriverManager.getConnection(connStr);
      if(con != null)
      {
         System.out.println("Connection succeeded");

         String dequeueQuery = "DECLARE " +
            " names namesarray;" +
            "   total integer;" +
            "   BEGIN " +
            "   names := namesarray('Kavita', 'Pritam', 'Ayan', 'Rishav', 'Aziz'); " +
            "   ? := names;"+
            " END;";

         CallableStatement cstmt = null;
         con.setAutoCommit(false);
         cstmt =(OracleCallableStatement)con.prepareCall(dequeueQuery);

         cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY,"NAMESARRAY");
         boolean b = cstmt.execute();
         Array arr = cstmt.getArray(1);

         String[] recievedArray = (String[]) arr.getArray();
         for (int i = 0; i < recievedArray.length; i++)
             System.out.println(recievedArray[i]);

         con.commit();
      }
      con.close();
    } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but we don't have create privileges to our user, that is why I declared a type. Do we have alternate to avoid create type?

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't think of alternate way if varray is used. To create a new `type` an user requires `resource` privilege. If the user already has `resource` privilege, then creating the type once will resolve all your issues. If anything comes in mind, i will definitely share. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using **ojdbc14.jar**

Try once with **[ojbc6.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadojdbc6jar.htm)** and it should work.